# How to insert values from 3 drop down list into 1 column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, drop-down-menu

How to insert values from 3 drop down list into 1 column in mysql

I'm using php.

I have a form with 3 drop down list for dates,
1. Day
2. Month
3. Year

How do I insert them as 1 date value to 1 column in mysql?

Comment: dot (.) is the string concatenator in php, not sure what else you need to know

Comment: I am unable to insert the values into mysql as my values for the month are spelled as full, i.e 'Janurary', therefore can't insert into mysql as it is in datetime format. Anyway to set the value for the month to 1 for Jan, but display it as January in the form?

Comment: @GabrielNg take a look on the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$year = $_POST['year_column'];    //YYYY
// Updated
// Cause you have months as String like January
$month = date('m', strtotime($_POST['month_column']));  //Return MM
$day = $_POST['day_column'];    //DD

$newDate = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
```

now insert the `$newDate` variable into your DataBase, one more set `datetime` datatype for your `date_field` in mysql.

**UPDATE:**

```
$months = array(1=>'January', 'February', ...); // Your Months in array
echo "<select name='month_column'>";
foreach( $months as $key=>$month){
echo "<otpion value='$key'>$month</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

and if you have `January` named of the month then take a look on this example http://codepad.org/p3pqbSlB this convert your month for `datetime` compatible.

also you should have to take a look on the PHP's [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

enjoy.

Comment: Hi, sorry but my values for the month are spelled as full, i.e 'Janurary', therefore can't insert into mysql as it is in datetime format. Anyway to set the value for the month to 1 for Jan, but display it as January in the form?

Comment: hi, sorry, but I don't understand the array, is there any way to do it as this: <option>January</option> but have the value as 1 for January?

Comment: @GabrielNg have you checked http://codepad.org/p3pqbSlB ?? this is the alternative.

Comment: @GabrielNg now check the above codes, i have updated according to your requirement.

Comment: hi, yeap, i've seen them, my form is working fine now, however, i'm unable to insert the date into mysql... here's my code: SET DeliveryDate=".STR_TO_DATE('$DeliveryDate','%Y','%m','%d')." I'm not sure whether is it right?

Answer (score 1):

```
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

$date = $month." ".$day.",".$year; 

$query = "INSERT INTO table_name(my_column) VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d,%m,%Y'))";
```

Combine your drop down selected values into a single string  `$date` using (.) dot concatenation operator and pass it to **`STR_TO_DATE()`** function that converts a string to date.

So suppose you pass string **May 1,2013** to `STR_TO_DATE()` function , the value inserted is of date  time type `2013-05-01`.

Eg.

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');
        -> '2013-05-01'
```

or

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013','%M %d,%Y');
        -> '2013-05-01'
```

Now for displaying this datetime value in full month name format use **`DATE_FORMAT()`** function.

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-05-01',  %M %d %Y');
        -> 'May 1 2013'
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure the column is date type

Then concatenate the values from the 3 dropdowns into a datestring

```
 // proper input for date into mysql = "Y-m-d" ("2013-01-23")
$dateString = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;
```